# Issue with date comparison in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am doing a date comparison in oracle.
When I execute the code below

```
select tr.x, tbi.y, to_char(tr.UPDATED_AT,'dd-mon-yyyy')
from  tbi, tb, tr
where
tbi.id=tb.id and
tb.id=tr.id  and 
tr.updated_at = to_date('23/02/2016', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

No row is selected

But when I execute the following query

```
select tr.x, tbi.y, to_char(tr.UPDATED_AT,'dd-mon-yyyy')
from  tbi, tb, tr
where
tbi.id=tb.id and
tb.id=tr.id 
and 
tr.updated_at > to_date('23/02/2016', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

I get this result

```
trx.x  tbi.y TO_CHAR(TR.UPDATED_AT,'DD-MM-YYYY')
123456  0    23-02-2016
12345   0    23-02-2016
123     0    23-02-2016
123123  0    23-02-2016
```

Why is the `>` operator showing dates which are equal and `=` is not showing the equal dates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use TRUNC()

```
select tr.x, tbi.y, to_char(tr.UPDATED_AT,'dd-mon-yyyy')
from  tbi, tb, tr
where
tbi.id=tb.id and
tb.id=tr.id 
and 
trunc(tr.updated_at) = to_date('23/02/2016', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

The problem with your query(I'm guessing by the look of it) your updated_at format is dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss .

So, 23/02/2016 is not equal to 23/02/2016 20:00:05 . (A default hh24:mi:ss of a date is 00:00:00)

Trunc() makes the date formated like dd/mm/yyyy and ignore the hours

Comment: Thanks. This is working but why is it not working without trunc?

Comment: I've explain it all @monvic

Comment: Got it. Thanks @sagi

Comment: No problem friend @monvic

Answer (score 0):

**problem**

```
tr.updated_at = to_date('23/02/2016', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

returns you only the results where `updated_at` equals `23/02/2016 00:00:00`

**solution**

Try the following instead:

```
trunc(tr.updated_at) = to_date('23/02/2016', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

cf [trunc function documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
Because updated_at column have the date with minutes and seconds. 
You are trying to fetch records for which updated_at has the value 
23/02/2016 00:00:00
```

Try this for desired output :

select tr.x, tbi.y, to_char(tr.UPDATED_AT,'dd-mon-yyyy')
    from  tbi, tb, tr
    where
    tbi.id=tb.id and
    tb.id=tr.id  and 
    to_char(tr.updated_at,'dd/mm/yyyy') = to_date('23/02/2016', 'dd/MM/yyyy')

Answer (score 0):

Using `TRUNC`, as suggested by other answers, makes it impossible to used indexes on this field (except function-based indexes). For that reason, you might prefer

```
tr.updated_at between to_date('23/02/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                  and to_date('23/02/2016 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: There is no indexing on the field but it is good to know for future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The clause

```
tr.updated_at = to_date('23/02/2016', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

is not returning any results due to the fact that the Updated_at field in the table TR being a date time field which stores a timestamp.

**Eg: 23-02-2016 00:00:00**

hence when you use the Equals operator, it returns false due to the missing timestamp on the RHS of the clause.

For performance reasons and to avoid ambiguity, I would advise the use of *between* with a date range or *Trunc*  function on Tr.Updated_at.

eg: Trunc(tr.updated_at) = to_date('23/02/2016', 'dd/MM/yyyy')